# Getting a value from an SQL database table

Tags: sql, sql-server

here is my code:

```
public int getMsgNum()
{
    string sqlStr = "Select MAX(MsgID) FROM Msgs";
    SqlDataAdapter daObj = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlStr, conStr);
    DataSet dsObj = new DataSet();
    daObj.Fill(dsObj);
    DataTableReader r = dsObj.Tables[0].CreateDataReader();
    return (int.Parse(r["MsgID"].ToString())+1);
}
```

I am trying to get the biggest value of MsgID that in the table. I have checked and the name are correct: there is a table which called `Msgs` and there is a column called `MsgID`, that is not where the problem. Alos the `conStr` is correct because i am able to insert the table using the same `conStr`.

here is the exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: DataTableReader is invalid for current DataTable &#39;Table&#39;.
at System.Data.DataTableReader.get_Item(String name)
at WebService.getMsgNum() in c:\Users\Omer\Desktop\project-Worker4\ServerSide\App_Code\WebService.cs:line 264
at WebService.sendMsg(String Sender, String Reciver, String Topic, String Contecnt) in c:\Users\Omer\Desktop\project-Worker4\ServerSide\App_Code\WebService.cs:line 95
```

it doesnt say anything to me

Comment: You tell us. This is like saying "hey, doctor, I am sick, what do I have?". Basically I am quite sure you get some sort of excption - but if you do not care enough about tellingus which, I actually care to vote to close.

Comment: "I'm doing everything right!" - classic young programmer mistake.  Best idea is to fire up a debugger and see how the real behavior is not matching your incorrect assumptions.  You'll figure it out faster that way than wasting time asking here.  Debugging is an important skill to develop - go practice.

Comment: i added the exception which i dont understand, i hoped you could see the error in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in:

```
DataTableReader r = dsObj.Tables[0].CreateDataReader();
return (int.Parse(r["MsgID"].ToString())+1);
```

Why do you construct a `DataTableReader` of `dsObj.Tables[0]`? Can't you just read the value at `dsObj.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]`

Alternatively you can use

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Connection_String");
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select MAX(MsgID) FROM Msgs", connection);
object maxValue = command.ExecuteScalar();
return (int.Parse(maxValue) + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

sh_kamath is right in his answer.

and for your code the problem is you forgot add `read()` method.

following shud work

```
public int getMsgNum()
{
    string sqlStr = "Select MAX(MsgID) FROM Msgs";
    SqlDataAdapter daObj = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlStr, conStr);
    DataSet dsObj = new DataSet();
    daObj.Fill(dsObj);
    DataTableReader r = dsObj.Tables[0].CreateDataReader();
    int int1 = 0;
    while (r.Read())
    {
        int1 = int.Parse(r["MsgID"].ToString())+1;
    }
    return int1;
}
```